# Mpu6050 not detecting in nodemcu

Tags: arduino, nodemcu, mpu6050

I am trying to interface mpu6050 to nodemcu as follow:

```
Vcc - 3v
Gnd - gnd
Sda - D2
Scl - D1
```

But it's not detecting the sensor
The sensor works with Arduino with connection

```
Vcc - 5v
Gnd - gnd
Sda - A5
Scl - A4
INT - d2
```

The code I tried was the Arduino example code with additional
Wire.begin(D2,D1) in nodemcu

Comment: I can't help but noticing that the setup that worked involved one extra connection not present in the one that didn't work.

Comment: yes you are right but the issue is as you can see the d2 pin which is used as INT in Arduino is already used as SDA in nodemcu and i tried to connect to almost all other pins but its not working.Thanks for your interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had imported this library 
https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050
and run the example code with wiring as
Vcc - 3v
Gnd - gnd
Sda - D2
Scl - D1 
and instead of writing Wire.begin(D2,D1) i wrote Wire.begin() and it worked.